# Issues regarding closing tag elements and attachable properties?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, stackpanel

Can anyone help me figure out whats wrong with this piece of xaml code? Basically what happened was I removed a listbox from the xaml and cs  as it wasn't needed and now it's returning these errors, I'm sure its something obvious that I'm missing here!
apologies for what is probably a noob question

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you seem to have two StackPanel start tags but only one StackPanel end tag under your ContentPanel Grid. What errors do you get if you add the missing StackPanel end tag before th first Grid end tag?

Thanks

Paul Diston

Comment: after I've added the second </stackpanel> before </grid> I'm getting : "The attachable property 'ApplicationBar' was not found in type 'PhoneApplicationPage " and  "Closing tag for element '<phone:PhoneApplicationPage>' was not found"

Comment: Is there anyway you can provide the complete XAML?

Comment: Two things, your closing Tag </phone:ApplicationPage>  needs to read </phone:PhoneApplicationPage> and the <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar> defnition needs to be just before </phone:PhoneApplicationPage> and not inside the closing Grid tag.

Comment: I understand the first bit, error cleared. But the second part to your answer I'm having trouble with, are you sure it's not supposed to be in the grid? if possible could you provide the revised section of xaml?

Comment: This is the revised XAML http://sharetext.org/DFWH. If you open the default MainPage.xaml of a new project you will see that the ApplicationBar is always defined just above the closing PhoneApplicationPage tag.

Comment: You may be interested in reading the following which details why the ApplicationBar needs to be defined in the way it is : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/06/18/why-are-the-applicationbar-objects-not-frameworkelements.aspx

Comment: I had a feeling thats what you meant, and you're right about the application bar on a new project. However still getting similar errors even after your revised xaml :/ http://postimage.org/image/ntlbkonpz/  this baffles me

Comment: If you copy the XAML as I provided in the previous sharetext link then you should not be presented with those errors any more.

Comment: Ah brilliant, sorry didn't see your sharetext url on first glance! Problem solved, I appreciate your time David!

Answer (score 1):

The `</Grid>` element with the error is missing a `</StackPanel>` before it...

It's the 3rd error message on the bottom, stating "Closing tag for element 'StackPanel' was not found"!

Comment: ah yes Pedro, needed to add a second closing tag for stackpanel, well spotted!